# how do I push or append a hash onto a multidimensional hash in perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, hash, push

The following code creates a multidimensional hash of hashes, if that's the correct phrase. (Is there a better description?)

Each new subhash of `$CRIT{sourcefile}{raw}`
is created by 4 lines of code. (The `chunk` subhash is included only as a reminder that there will be several other hashes inside this array.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
my $index=0;
my %CRIT;
$CRIT{chunk}{raw}{1}{ANDOR} = 'ORNOT';
$index++;
$CRIT{sourcefile}{raw}{$index}{ANDOR} = 'OR';
$CRIT{sourcefile}{raw}{$index}{regex} = 'Woody\s+Guthrie';
$CRIT{sourcefile}{raw}{$index}{mod} = '';
$index++;
$CRIT{sourcefile}{raw}{$index}{ANDOR} = 'ANDNOT';
$CRIT{sourcefile}{raw}{$index}{regex} = '((Seeger)|(Baez))';
$CRIT{sourcefile}{raw}{$index}{mod} = 'i';
print Dumper \%CRIT;
my %NOWhash;
%NOWhash = (
   'ANDOR' => 'OR',
   'regex' => '\bUtah\s*Phill?ips\b',
   'mod' => 'i',
);
print Dumper \%NOWhash;
```

But consider `%NOWhash`, created at the bottom. Is there a way to  `push` or otherwise add `%NOWhash` to `$CRIT{sourcefile}{raw}`? If so, is there a way to assign a specific `$index` to it?

Comment: Why are you suing a hash as an array??? `$CRIT{sourcefile}{raw}{$index}{ANDOR}` should be `$CRIT{sourcefile}{raw}[$index]{ANDOR}`

Comment: Because I don't understand hashes and how they differ from arrays. I made your suggested change in the code,  and now each `raw` hash or subarray starts with an `undef`  value, before the components that I specify. Where does that value from from?

Comment: The first index of arrays is 0. But having an array will allow you to use `push` instead of tracking the last index manually: `push @{ $CRIT{sourcefile}{raw} }, \%NOWhash;`

Comment: Feel free to answer your own questions, but don't do so by replacing the question. Post your answers as Answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one has a sequence of items, an array is usually the most appropriate structure.

```
my %CRIT;
$CRIT{chunk}{raw} = [
   {
      ANDOR => 'ORNOT',
   },
   {
      ANDOR => 'OR',
      regex => 'Woody\s+Guthrie',
      mod   => '',
   },
   {
      ANDOR => 'ANDNOT',
      regex => '((Seeger)|(Baez))',
      mod   => 'i',
   },
];

push @{ $CRIT{chunk}{raw} }, {
   ANDOR => 'OR',
   regex => '\bUtah\s*Phill?ips\b',
   mod   => 'i',
);
```

See:

- [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](https://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)